# I would like to delete a row by clicking on it

Tags: android, android-sqlite

In this app the user adds a product to their shopping list.Then he can view his products added to shopping list by switching to the class below.Now I want the user to have the option to delete the product by clicking on the row that the product is stored in,I would like to know how that is possible ?Thank you .

*DataListActivity*

```
 package ie.example.artur.projectrepeat;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DataListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    ListView listView;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    DatabaseClass  database;
    Cursor cursor;
    ListDataAdapter listDataAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.data_list_layout);


        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        listDataAdapter = new ListDataAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row_layout);
        listView.setAdapter(listDataAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        database = new DatabaseClass(getApplicationContext());

        sqLiteDatabase = database.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor=database.getInformation(sqLiteDatabase);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                String id, product_name, category;
                id = cursor.getString(0);
                product_name = cursor.getString(1);
                category = cursor.getString(2);
                DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(id, product_name, category);
                listDataAdapter.add(dataProvider);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext()


                    );

        }
    }

   @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_id);
        sqLiteDatabase = database.getReadableDatabase();
        DatabaseClass.DeleteInformation(tv.getText().toString(), sqLiteDatabase);


        listDataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    }


    }
```

And this is my Database

```
  package ie.example.artur.projectrepeat;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;

/**
 * Created by family on 06/07/2016.
 */
public class DatabaseClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_Name = "Product.db2";
    public static final String Table_Name = "product_table2";
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "Name";
    public static final String COL_3 = "Quantity";
    public static final String COL_4 = "Category";
    public static final String COL_5 = "Importance";
    public DatabaseClass(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_Name, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + Table_Name + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,Quantity TEXT,Category INTEGER,Importance TEXT);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("Drop Table If Exists" + Table_Name);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String name, String quantity, String category,String importance) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2, name);
        contentValues.put(COL_3, quantity);
        contentValues.put(COL_4, category);
        contentValues.put(COL_5, importance);

        long result = db.insert(Table_Name, null, contentValues);

            if (result == -1)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }

    public Cursor getAllData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + Table_Name, null);
        return res;
    }

    public boolean updateData(String id,String name,String quantity,String category,String importance ) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_1, id);
        contentValues.put(COL_2, name);
        contentValues.put(COL_3, quantity);
        contentValues.put(COL_4, category);
        contentValues.put(COL_5, importance);
        db.update(Table_Name,contentValues,"id =?",new String[]{id});
                return true;
    }

   /* public Cursor getCursor(){
        SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        queryBuilder.setR
    }
*/
   public Integer DeleteData (String id) {
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
       return db.delete(Table_Name,"ID = ?",new String[]{id});
   }
    public static void DeleteInformation(String item_name, SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase){

        String selection = COL_1+" LIKE ?";
        String [] selection_args = {item_name};
        sqLiteDatabase.delete(Table_Name,selection,selection_args);

    }

    public Cursor getInformation(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase)
    {
        Cursor cursor;
        String [] Projections = {COL_1,COL_2,COL_4};

        cursor  = sqLiteDatabase.query(Table_Name,Projections,null,null,null,null,null);
        return cursor;

    }

    public Cursor getItem(String item_name ,SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase){
        String [] Projections = {COL_1,COL_2,COL_3,COL_4,COL_5};
        String selection = COL_1+" LIKE ?";
        String [] selection_args = {item_name};
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(Table_Name,Projections,selection,selection_args,null,null,null);
        return cursor;

    }


}
```

*Data Provider*

```
package ie.example.artur.projectrepeat;

/**
 * Created by family on 10/08/2016.
 */
public class DataProvider {

    private String id;
    private String product_name;
    private String category;

    public DataProvider(String id,String product_name,String category)
    {
    this.id = id;
    this.product_name=product_name;
    this.category=category;




    }


    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getProduct_name() {
        return product_name;
    }

    public void setProduct_name(String product_name) {
        this.product_name = product_name;
    }
}
```

*ListDataActivity*

```
package ie.example.artur.projectrepeat;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by family on 10/08/2016.
 */
public class ListDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter  {
   List list = new ArrayList ();

    public ListDataAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }





    static class LayoutHandler
    {
        TextView id,product_name,category;

    }
    @Override
    public void add(Object object) {
        super.add(object);
        list.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();

    }



    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       LayoutHandler layoutHandler;
        View row = convertView;
        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
            layoutHandler = new LayoutHandler();
            layoutHandler.id = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.product_id);
            layoutHandler.product_name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
            layoutHandler.category = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.product_category);
            row.setTag(layoutHandler);
        }
        else {
            layoutHandler = (LayoutHandler) row.getTag();

        }
        DataProvider dataProvider = (DataProvider) this.getItem(position);
        layoutHandler.id.setText(dataProvider.getId());
        layoutHandler.product_name.setText(dataProvider.getProduct_name());
        layoutHandler.category.setText(dataProvider.getCategory());



        return row;




    }


    }
```

Comment: Attach an OnItemClickListener to your ListView and then get your item and delete its record from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView tv=view.findViewBtId(R.id.product_id);
        databaseObject.DeleteData(tv.getText().toString());
        listAdapter.removeItemAt(position);
         // to close the current activity
         finish();

    }
});
```

Set setOnItemClickListener as above code on your ListView.

I am adding removeItemAt method in your adapter class

```
    package ie.example.artur.projectrepeat;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    /**
     * Created by family on 10/08/2016.
     */
    public class ListDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter  {
       List list = new ArrayList ();

        public ListDataAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
            super(context, resource);
        }





        static class LayoutHandler
        {
            TextView id,product_name,category;

        }
        @Override
        public void add(Object object) {
            super.add(object);
            list.add(object);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();

        }



        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return list.get(position);
        }
        // pass you item position which you want to remove
        public void removeItemAt(int position){
        list.remove(position);
        this.notifyDataStateChange();
        }    

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
           LayoutHandler layoutHandler;
            View row = convertView;
            if(row == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
                layoutHandler = new LayoutHandler();
                layoutHandler.id = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.product_id);
                layoutHandler.product_name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
                layoutHandler.category = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.product_category);
                row.setTag(layoutHandler);
            }
            else {
                layoutHandler = (LayoutHandler) row.getTag();

            }
            DataProvider dataProvider = (DataProvider) this.getItem(position);
            layoutHandler.id.setText(dataProvider.getId());
            layoutHandler.product_name.setText(dataProvider.getProduct_name());
            layoutHandler.category.setText(dataProvider.getCategory());



            return row;




        }


        }
```

Comment: use your adapter object which is  listDataAdapter

Comment: `listDataAdapter.removeItemAt(position);` it says here it cannot resolve `removeItemAt`

Comment: please post your adapter class so I will modify it and show you how to remove the item.

Comment: are you success to delete the record from database?

Comment: Yes I can remove the item but I'm having a little issue ,when I delete it ,I to need leave the activity and come back to see the change ,I will update the code now

Comment: please check about updated code .i added one method in your adapter class. and to close current activity use finish() method as i added in your itemClickListener.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.If you have time I'm trying to get the update working here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38923502/how-to-update-using-a-custom-dialog ,I would appreciate it if you could give me some advice .

Comment: Yeah sure. i will help.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you will want to set an OnClickListener on either the row or create a button in the cell that has an attached listener. then inside the listener remove that item from the array of items and from the database. Im not going to write the code for you but to give you an example of an OnClickListener:

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click 
                // delete this item from the database
                (new DatabaseClass()).DeleteData(list.get(position).id);  
                // delete this item from the list array
                list.remove(position);

                // reload the listview
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

In the getView() method of your Adapter you would want to add this onclick listener right after setting your layout handler values. 
Hopefully this at least gives you an idea of what to do. There are a bunch of different approaches you could take but i would highly recommend against making the whole row clickable, use a button with "remove" on it instead. and consider showing a confirmation modal first before performing the action of removing the data.

Comment: I think I put in the wrong class into the question by accident because it doesn't seem to work when I try to write the code ,I have changed the class ,can you tell me if this is the right class to put the OnClickListener ?