# How to update data in a Custom Dialog

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-dialog, customdialog

The user at the moment clicks on a row which contains data and a Dialog with text fields is displayed.
I want the user to update the strings by using this Dialog.

How can I do this?

I have an update method already in my Database Class, but I'm not sure how to implement the update in the Dialog

[image]
[image]

Database Class

```
package ie.example.artur.projectrepeat;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;

/**
 * Created by family on 06/07/2016.
 */
public class DatabaseClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_Name = "Product.db2";
    public static final String Table_Name = "product_table2";
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "Name";
    public static final String COL_3 = "Quantity";
    public static final String COL_4 = "Category";
    public static final String COL_5 = "Importance";
    Context myContext;


    public DatabaseClass(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_Name, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + Table_Name + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,Quantity TEXT,Category INTEGER,Importance TEXT);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("Drop Table If Exists" + Table_Name);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String name, String quantity, String category,String importance) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2, name);
        contentValues.put(COL_3, quantity);
        contentValues.put(COL_4, category);
        contentValues.put(COL_5, importance);

        long result = db.insert(Table_Name, null, contentValues);

            if (result == -1)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }

    public Cursor getAllData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + Table_Name, null);
        return res;
    }

    public boolean updateData(String id,String name,String quantity,String category,String importance ) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_1, id);
        contentValues.put(COL_2, name);
        contentValues.put(COL_3, quantity);
        contentValues.put(COL_4, category);
        contentValues.put(COL_5, importance);
        db.update(Table_Name,contentValues,"id =?",new String[]{id});
                return true;
    }

   /* public Cursor getCursor(){
        SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        queryBuilder.setR
    }
*/
   public Integer DeleteData (String id) {
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
       return db.delete(Table_Name,"ID = ?",new String[]{id});
   }
    public static void DeleteInformation(String item_name, SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase){

        String selection = COL_1+" LIKE ?";
        String [] selection_args = {item_name};
        sqLiteDatabase.delete(Table_Name,selection,selection_args);

    }

    public Cursor getInformation(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase)
    {
        Cursor cursor;
        String [] Projections = {COL_1,COL_2,COL_4};

        cursor  = sqLiteDatabase.query(Table_Name,Projections,null,null,null,null,null);
        return cursor;

    }

    public Cursor getItem(String item_name ,SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase){
        String [] Projections = {COL_1,COL_2,COL_3,COL_4,COL_5};
        String selection = COL_1+" LIKE ?";
        String [] selection_args = {item_name};
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(Table_Name,Projections,selection,selection_args,null,null,null);
        return cursor;

    }


}
```

EditActivity

```
package ie.example.artur.projectrepeat;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Edit_Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    ListView listView;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    DatabaseClass  database;
    Cursor cursor;
    ListDataAdapter listDataAdapter;
    Dialog d;
    EditText editText_name,editText_Quantity,editText_Category,editTextId,editText_Number;


    Button updateBtn;
    EditText nameEditText;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.data_list_layout);



        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        listDataAdapter = new ListDataAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row_layout);
        listView.setAdapter(listDataAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        database = new DatabaseClass(getApplicationContext());
        editText_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_name);
        editText_Quantity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Quantity);
        editText_Category = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Category);
        editText_Number = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_Number);
        editTextId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_id);
        sqLiteDatabase = database.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor=database.getInformation(sqLiteDatabase);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                String id, product_name, category;
                id = cursor.getString(0);
                product_name = cursor.getString(1);
                category = cursor.getString(2);
                DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(id, product_name, category);
                listDataAdapter.add(dataProvider);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext()


                    );

        }

    }

    public void loginMethod() {
        // Create an instance of the dialog fragment and show it
        MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
        dialog.show(getFragmentManager(),"my_dialog");
    }

/*
    private void showDialog(){
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.input);
        dialog.setTitle("Here Goes the Title");

        Button updateBtn = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.updateBtn);


        dialog.show();
    }
*/



    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position , long id) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_id);



        sqLiteDatabase = database.getReadableDatabase();

        loginMethod();

/*
        listView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // custom dialog
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.input);
                dialog.setTitle("Title...");


                final EditText nameEditText = (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
                Button updateBtn = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.updateBtn);


             /*   if (position == -1) {

                    updateBtn.setEnabled(false);
                } else

                    updateBtn.setEnabled(true);


                updateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                    }

                });
                dialog.show();
            }

        });
*/
    /*private void displayInputDialog(final int pos) {
        d = new Dialog(this);
        d.setTitle("List View");
        d.setContentView(R.layout.input);

        final EditText nameEditText = (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
        Button updateBtn = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.updateBtn);


        if (pos == -1) {

            updateBtn.setEnabled(false);
        } else

            updateBtn.setEnabled(true);


        updateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });*
        }*/
            }




        }
```

MyDialog Class

```
package ie.example.artur.projectrepeat;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * Created by family on 12/08/2016.
 */
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment{


    LayoutInflater inflater;

    View v;
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.input,null);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setView(v).setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a neat way to handle custom dialog class!

You can make **MyDialog** class to contain Builder class so that it handles buttonOnClick methods and text data.

**my_dialog_layout.xml** should contains 4 editTexts(name, category, quantity, importance) and 3 buttons(update, cancel, ok), as it is shown in your second picture. I won't post the xml code since it's not the critical part.

So  in OnItemClickListener of the listView in **EditActivity**, you can

1. build the dialog
2. set default text on edit texts
3. set onClickListener for buttons

---

**MyDialog class**

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {

   public static final String SimpleName = MyDialog.class.getSimpleName();
   private EditText name,category, quantity, importance;
   private Button update, positive, negative;
   private Builder builder;

    private static MyDialog instance = new MyDialog();

    public static MyDialog getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }

   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.setCancelable(true);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            if (builder != null) {
                builder = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(Builder.class.getSimpleName());
            }
        }
        setRetainInstance(true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        // make the dialog's default background transparent so that you can customize the window
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        return dialog;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog_layout, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        initViews(view);
        if (builder != null) {

            if (builder.getTextName() != null) {
                name.setText(builder.getTextName());
            }
            if (builder.getTextCategory() != null) {
                category.setText(builder.getTextCategory());
            }
            if (builder.getTextQuantity() != null) {
                quantity.setText(builder.getTextQuantity());
            }
            if (builder.getTextImportance() != null) {
                importance.setText(builder.getTextImportance());
            }



            update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    builder.getOnUpdateClicked().OnClick(view, getDialog());
                }
            });

            positive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   builder.getOnPositiveClicked().OnClick(view, getDialog());
                }
            });

            negative.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  builder.getOnNegativeClicked().OnClick(view, getDialog());
                }
            });

        }
    }

    private void initViews(View view) {       
        name = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_name);
        category = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id. editText_category);
        quantity = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id. editText_quantity);
        importance = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_importance);
        update = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.update);
        positive = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.positive);
        negative = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.negative);

    }

    private Dialog show(Activity activity, Builder builder) {             
         this.builder = builder;
         if (!isAdded()){
             show(((AppCompatActivity) activity).getSupportFragmentManager(), SimpleName);
         }
         return getDialog();
     }

    public static class Builder implements Parcelable  {

        private OnPositiveClicked onPositiveClicked;
        private OnNegativeClicked onNegativeClicked;
        private OnUpdateClicked onUpdateClicked;

        private textName;
        private textCategory;
        private textQuantity;
        private textImportance;

        private Context context;

        protected Builder(Parcel in) {
            textName = in.readString();
            textCategory = in.readString();
            textQuantity = in.readString();
            textImportance = in.readString();
        }

        public static final Creator<Builder> CREATOR = new Creator<Builder>() {
            @Override
            public Builder createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new Builder(in);
            }

            @Override
            public Builder[] newArray(int size) {
                return new Builder[size];
            }
        };

        public Context getContext() {
            return context;
        }

        public Builder setActivity(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public Builder setTextName(String textName) {
            this.textName = textName;
            return this;
        }

        public String getTextName() {
            return textName;
        }

        public Builder setTextCategory(String textCategory) {
            this.textCategory = textCategory;
            return this;
        }

        public String getTextCategory() {
            return textCategory;
        }

        public Builder setTextQuantity(String textQuantity) {
            this.textQuantity = textQuantity;
            return this;
        }

        public String getTextQuantity() {
            return textQuantity;
        }

        public Builder setTextImportance(String textImportance) {
            this.textImportance = textImportance;
            return this;
        }

        public String getTextImportance() {
            return textImportance;
        }


        public OnPositiveClicked getOnPositiveClicked() {
            return onPositiveClicked;
        }

        public Builder setOnPositiveClicked(OnPositiveClicked onPositiveClicked) {
            this.onPositiveClicked = onPositiveClicked;
            return this;
        }

        public OnNegativeClicked getOnNegativeClicked() {
            return onNegativeClicked;
        }

        public Builder setOnNegativeClicked(OnNegativeClicked onNegativeClicked) {
            this.onNegativeClicked = onNegativeClicked;
            return this;
        }

        public OnUpdateClicked getOnUpdateClicked() {
            return onUpdateClicked;
        }

        public Builder setOnUpdateClicked(OnUpdateClicked onUpdateClicked) {
            this.onUpdateClicked = onUpdateClicked;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder build() {
            return this;
        }

        public Dialog show() {
            return getInstance().show(((Activity) context), this);
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
            parcel.writeString(textName);
            parcel.writeString(textCategory);
            parcel.writeString(textQuantity);
            parcel.writeString(textImportance);
        }

    }

    public interface OnPositiveClicked {
        void OnClick(View view, Dialog dialog);
    }

    public interface OnNegativeClicked {
        void OnClick(View view, Dialog dialog);
    }


}
```

---

**EditActivity**

build and show MyDialog in a listview OnItemClickListner.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            MyDialog.Builder dialog=null;

            // TODO get the strings from database at the position i
            String name = 
            String category = 
            String quantity = 
            String importance = 

            dialog.setTextName(name)
                .setTextCategory(category)
                .setTextQuantity(quantity)
                .setTextImportance(importance)
                .setOnPositiveClicked(new MyDialog.OnPositiveClicked() { 
                             @Override
                            public void OnClick(View view, Dialog dialog) {

                            }
                        })
                .setOnNegativeClicked(new MyDialog.OnNegativeClicked() { 
                            @Override
                            public void OnClick(View view, Dialog dialog) {

                            }
                        })
                .setOnUpdateClicked(new MyDialog.OnUpdateClicked() { 
                            @Override
                            public void OnClick(View view, Dialog dialog) {
                                // TODO update database here
                            }
                        })

                .build();
                dialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Hope it helps. Let me know if there is a mistake or a better way.